# How to display data from mysql embed in html

Tags: php

Hey i want to display some html/css depending on how many rows there are in database basically. Is there a way to do this without echo? Because i'm lost when i have to use many ' '. Here is code sample

```
<?php foreach ($result as $row) {

}?>
    <div id="abox">
    <div class="abox-top">
    Order x
    </div>
    <div class="abox-panel">
      <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="abox-top">
    lorem</div>
    <div class="abox-panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ac convallis diam, vitae rhoncus enim. Proin eu turpis at ligula posuere condimentum nec eu massa. Donec porta tellus ante, non semper risus sagittis at. Pellentesque sollicitudin sodales fringilla. Ut efficitur urna eget arcu luctus lobortis. Proin ut tellus non lacus dapibus vehicula non sit amet ante. Ut nibh justo, posuere sit amet fringilla eget, aliquam mattis urna.</p>

    </div>
```

Comment: you want to display data from database too?

Comment: Yes .. but for now just rows

Comment: yes you can but again you will lost in many `<?php` `{` `}` `?>` tags

Comment: There are hundreds of tutorials on displaying data from a database in HTML.

Comment: well i rather use <?php tags in html code rather than having whole <?php and then adding html into <?php it's very confusing and not elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing complicated about it:

Simple/ugly:

```
<?php while($row = fetch()) { ?>
<div>
    <?php echo $row['somefield'] ?>
</div>
<? } ?>
```

Alternative:

```
<?php

while ($row = fetch()) {
    echo <<<EOL
<div>
     {$row['somefield']}
</div>
EOL;
}
```

and then of course there's any number of templating systems, which claim to separate logic from display, and then litter the display with their OWN logic system anyways.

Comment: i think mentioning that the alternative is using heredoc so he can search furthermore

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `<?=` short opening tag introduced in php 5.3 before PHP 5.4.0 came out you had to enable short_open_tag ini but after 5.4.0 tag

here is an example

```
<?php $var='hello, world'; ?>

<?=$var ?> // outputs world
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Templates engines makes your life a pie

Take Smarty for example, it's pretty good template library. What template engine does is fetch variables to pre defined templates.

**Your code in simple php:**

```
<?php

echo 'My name is '. $name. ', that's why I'm awesome <br>';

foreach ($data as $value) {
   echo $value['name'].' is awesome to!';
}

?>
```

**Code in smarty:**

```
My name is {$name}, that's why I'm awesome <br>
{foreach $data as $value}
 {$value} is awesome to!
{/foreach}
```

*Template engines pros:*

- Templates are held in separate custom named files. (i.e users.tpl, registration.tpl etc)
- Smarty Caches your views (templates).
- Simple to use i.e {$views + ($viewsToday/$ratio)}.
- A lot of helpers.
- You can create custom plugins/functions.
- Easy to use and debug.
- **Most importantly**: It separates your php code from html!

*Template engines cons:*

- Sometimes hard to grip the concept of working for beginner.
- Don't know any more actually

Answer (score 0):

When I dont want to use a template engine (I like Twig, btw), I do something like this:

1) Write a separate file with the html code and some custom tags where data should be presented:

file "row_template.html":

```
<div class="abox-top">{{ TOP }}</div>
<div class="abox-panel"><p>{{ PANEL }}</p></div>
```

2) And then, read that file and do the replacements in the loop:

```
$row_template = file_get_contents('row_template.html');

foreach ($result as $row) {

    $replaces = array(
        '{{ TOP }}'   => $row['top'],
        '{{ PANEL }}' => $row['panel']
    );

    print str_replace(
              array_keys($replaces), 
              array_values($replaces), 
              $row_template
          );

}
```

In addition, you can change the content of "row_template.html" without touching the php code.

Clean and nice to the eye!